# How to type hint an instance-level function (i.e. not a method)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Instance attributes are typically [annotated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) on the class:

```py
class Foo:
    x: int

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

Foo(0).x
```

This works and mypy doesn't report any issues. However, when the instance attribute is a [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) then mypy starts complaining:

```py
from typing import Callable


class Foo:
    func: Callable[[], int]

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func


Foo(lambda: 0).func()
```

I get the following error:

```
test.py:11: error: Attribute function "func" with type "Callable[[], int]" does not accept self argument
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Since this function is not defined on the class, but only stored in the instance dict, it won't be bound to the instance during attribute lookup (in short: the above snippet works). So I don't see why mypy would complain about this. Is there another way to type hint such instance-level functions?

Comment: It believes that the function you're passing through is like any other method (requires self as the first argument). If you were to pass a argument into the lambda `lambda s: 0` then mypy shouldn't complain like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently broken in mypy as it assumes you are creating a method, here is the relevant issue https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/708.

Typing the function in the init works fine as it won't think it's a method on the class, the following code passes type checking properly and `func`'s type is inferred from the parameter. The attribute assignment can also be typed directly if the parameter is not viable.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[], int]):
        self.func = func

reveal_type(Foo(lambda: 0).func)
###OUTPUT###
file.py:7: note: Revealed type is "def () -> builtins.int"
```

An another workaround that can be found in the issue and avoids assigning in the init is to use a callback [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) like so:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class FuncCallback(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, /) -> int:
        ...

class Foo:
    func: FuncCallback

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
```

This makes `func` a `FuncCallback` protocol which expects no arguments when called and returns an `int` like your `Callable`.